# Html Helper - RadioButtonForSelectList adding name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using the below Html Helper, however the optional **name** argument is not working as expected.

So in some cases I want to send a custom name as argument just like we do with the **id**, using the `htmlAttribute`.

Somehow the **name `htmlAttribute` is not getting outputted**, so I am still getting the default automatic generated name.

**Full Code block below**

```
public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonForSelectList<TModel, TProperty>(
            this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
            Expression<Func<TModel, 
            TProperty>> expression,
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listOfValues, 
            string name = "")
{
    var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (listOfValues != null)
    {
       // Create a radio button for each item in the list 
       foreach (SelectListItem item in listOfValues)
       {
          // Generate an id to be given to the radio button field 
          var id = string.Format("{0}_{1}", metaData.PropertyName, item.Value);

          // Create and populate a radio button using the existing html helpers 
          var label = htmlHelper.Label(id, item.Text);
          string radio;

          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
          {
              radio = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, item.Value, new { id = id}).ToHtmlString();
          }
          else
          {
              radio = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, item.Value, new { id = id, name = name }).ToHtmlString();
          }



// Create the html string that will be returned to the client e.g. 

           sb.AppendFormat("<div class=\"RadioButton\">{0}{1}</div>", radio, label);
       }
    }

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, item.Value)` should automatically generate the it for you

Comment: Can you please clarify @Murali?

Comment: I have used like `htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, myValue, new { id, disabled = "disabled" }).ToHtmlString()` and it is generates name automatically for me.

Comment: @Murali as I wrote on the question : "in some cases I want to send a custom name as argument".

Comment: I'm not sure how you can pull that off without writing your own helper, but why do you want to? It'll break any binding that MVC may use the name field for.

Comment: @SethMW I don't understand why the htmlAttribute for name does not work, while others like id work fine. It's for a specific scenario that would take half an hour to explain here :)

Comment: It doesn't work, because it was designed not to. MVC generates that attribute itself, and has it's own expectation of what the value should be for binding, etc. I'd suggest whipping up a custom Html Helper if you really need to override that attribute.